# How can I remove extra space in empty xml tags

Tags: python, xml.etree

I have a xml file where I'm looking for specific tag (for example: tag `<x>`) and if I find him I replace/update its value to specific text (for example: *test*).

Python version 3.5.0.

**Sample xml file:**

```
<root>
 <a/>
 <b>0</b>
 <c/>
 <x>some value</x>
</root>
```

**This is my code:**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

datafile = 'input.xml'     # path to the source xml file
datafile_out = 'output.xml'    # path to the updated xml
tree = et.parse(datafile)
tree.find('.//x').text ='TEST'  # find <x> tag and write there value "TEST"
tree.write(datafile_out)    #generating updated xml file
```

**And this is my output:**

```
<root>
 <a />
 <b>0</b>
 <c />
 <x>TEST</x>
</root>
```

Everything works as expected.

But my problem is with extra space in empty tags: `<a />`
between tag name ***"a"*** and ***"slash"*** which wasn't present in input xml file.

I'm working with quite big xml files with a lot of empty tags so every extra space makes this files a lot bigger.

Is there any possible way to stop *ElementTree.write()* to add that extra space?

*Note:* I would like to use build in Python modules and not install third parties solutions.

Many thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using regular expressions.

As an example:

yourXmlAsString.replaceAll(">\s*<", "><");
Would remove all whitespaces between every XML element.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your reply :)
I did think of this approach to the problem but as I'm new to Python I thought I first ask if someone knows some more proper or elegant way to solve this